# How to remove the comments blocks from module front office output

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Modules in PS 1.7 that renders something in the front office displays like this:

```
    <!-- begin modules/jemaa//views/templates/widget/url.tpl --> 
Rendered string here 
    <!-- end modules/jemaa//views/templates/widget/url.tpl -->
```

How to get rid of these comments and get only the "rendred string"?

In fact I need to display a url string in the `src` attribule of an `img` html tag.

Thanks in advance for your usual help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it is happening only in debug mode.
The corresponding code is in `classes/Smarty/SmartyResourceModule`,  in the `fetch` method:

```
        if (_PS_MODE_DEV_) {
            $source = implode('', array(
                '<!-- begin ' . $file . ' -->',
                file_get_contents($file),
                '<!-- end ' . $file . ' -->',
            ));
        } else {
            $source = file_get_contents($file);
        }
```

Thank you for your time anyways.